# Autoprefix loader breaks scss compilation in Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loader, webpack, autoprefixer

I'm unable to get [autoprefixer-loader](https://github.com/passy/autoprefixer-loader) 1.10 to prefix my scss/css (apparently 1.20 is broken). After adding the loader, it no longer compiles mixins properly. When I remove the errored mixins, it compiles, but doesn't prefix. Here's Webpack's compilation details from terminal, and my module structure. Any help would be appreciated.

https://gist.github.com/zachshallbetter/efafbffa7e08bcc0aab4

```
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'app/scripts')
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$|\.css$/,
      loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.svg$|\.woff$|\.ttf$|\.wav$|\.mp3$/,
      loader: "file"
    },
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loader: "raw-loader"
    }]
  }
```

Comment: [some user](https://github.com/passy/autoprefixer-loader/issues/17#issuecomment-78096700) reported that a fresh enough version of sass-loader worked for him. If you cannot get this to work, maybe it's better to go directly through autoprefixer-loader issue tracker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As autoprefixer-loader is deprecated and they encourage us to use postcss instead (https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader), I made this config that is also working:

```
test: /\.scss/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'
```

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue. For me the issue was that I was including the sass-loader before the autoprefixer-loader. The autoprefixer-loader needs to first convert the css, which then converts to sass.

Looking at your log(line 83 for instance), I can see that this is indeed the case for you also. Changing the following in your webpack.config from:

```
loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader'
```

to:

```
loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!sass-loader'
```

Should do the trick. I hope that works!

Comment: I was under the impression that these loaders run right-to-left.

Comment: "When chaining loaders, they are applied right to left (from the file, back)."
- from the [Webpack docs on Loaders](https://webpack.github.io/docs/loaders.html)

Comment: krry , you are absolutely right, will modify answer.

Comment: thank you. how hard is to find these webpack config stuff